# Replace values of 0 in dataframe using mathematical formulas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes as below and I am trying to replace the `0` values from column `Price` in the first one.

The first dataframe looks like this:

| Region | Country | Product | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2016 | 500 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2017 | 400 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2018 | 0 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2019 | 450 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2016 | 750 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2017 | 0 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2018 | 0 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2019 | 890 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2016 | 0 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2017 | 0 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2018 | 415 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2019 | 0 |

It contains price for each type of product for each country for a given year. Some countries have values of `0` for certain years as that data is missing.

The second dataframe contains the average yearly price growth for each region and product and looks like this.

| Region | Product | Average Yearly Price Growth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | ABC | 0.043 |
| Africa | DEF | 0.071 |
| Africa | XYZ | 0.0128 |
| Asia | XYZ | 0.05 |
| Asia | ABC | -0.009 |
| Asia | DEF | 0.021 |

The task is to replace all `0` values in the first dataframe with the previous year's value for that particular product in that particular country, plus the average yearly rate increase (assuming the earliest data point is available).

In the case of product `DEF` in `Japan`, I would want to detect the earliest year where data is available and calculate all the previous years where `Price` is `0` from that point as follows:

Product `DEF` in `Japan` in `2018` has a `price` of `415` and is the earliest available data point for `Price`. Therefore the `price` for `2017` should be `415/(1+0.021)=406.464`. After that, the value for `2016` should be `406.464/(1+0.021)`. Once these values have been calculated, the value for `DEF` in `Japan` in `2019` should be `415+415*0.021=423.715`.

For other countries such as `South Africa` where the price for the earliest year (`2016`) is available  it should be easier. For example, for product `XYZ` in `South Africa` in `2017`, instead of `0` the value should be `750+750*0.0128=759.6`. Where `750` is the previous year value for that product in that country and `0.0128` is the average yearly price growth for that product in Africa (from dataframe 2).

Then for the same product but in 2018, the value should be the previously calculated one, `759.6+759.6*0.0128=769.32`.

Here is the sample data:

```
data1 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 400, 0,450,750,0,0,890,0,0,415,0]}

data2 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Product': ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','XYZ','ABC','DEF'],
         'Average Yearly Price Growth': [0.043, 0.071, 0.0128,0.05,-0.009,0.021]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

My code so far is below, but it only works for situations where the earlies available point is available, like `South Africa`. Any ideas on how to deal with situations like `Japan`?

```
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
     if rows['Price']==0:
        try:
                    past_year_value = df[(df['Country']==rows['Country']) & (df['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df['Region']==rows['Region']) & (df['Year']==rows['Year']-1)]['Price'].values[0]
                    df.at[index,'Price'] = past_year_value + past_year_value*df2[(df2['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df2['Region']==rows['Region'])]['Average Yearly Price Growth'].values[0]
        except:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix add another for loop after that, this is more like forward fill and backward fill for the value of 0 , since we need to step , just like `bfill` and `ffill` chain

```
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
     if rows['Price']==0:
        try:
                    past_year_value = df[(df['Country']==rows['Country']) & (df['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df['Region']==rows['Region']) & (df['Year']==rows['Year']-1)]['Price'].values[0]
                    df.at[index,'Price'] = past_year_value + past_year_value*df2[(df2['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df2['Region']==rows['Region'])]['Average Yearly Price Growth'].values[0]
        except:
                    pass

df = df.iloc[::-1]
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
     if rows['Price']==0:
        try:
                    past_year_value = df[(df['Country']==rows['Country']) & (df['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df['Region']==rows['Region']) & (df['Year']==rows['Year']+1)]['Price'].values[0]
                    df.at[index,'Price'] = past_year_value /(1+df2[(df2['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df2['Region']==rows['Region'])]['Average Yearly Price Growth'].values[0])
        except:
                    pass
df = df.iloc[::-1]
Out[88]: 
    Region       Country Product  Year  Price
0   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2016    500
1   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2017    400
2   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2018    417
3   Africa  South Africa     ABC  2019    450
4   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2016    750
5   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2017    759
6   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2018    768
7   Africa  South Africa     XYZ  2019    890
8     Asia         Japan     DEF  2016    397
9     Asia         Japan     DEF  2017    406
10    Asia         Japan     DEF  2018    415
11    Asia         Japan     DEF  2019    423
```